# interchanging data in same row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a student table with the folowing fields :

```
sid     sname    gender
 1       xyz       m
 2       abc       f
 3        wxy      m
 4       jkl       f
```

I want to interchange data in gender column as male to female and female to male.

I have tried this with a stored procedure as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[replacesex]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @sex char(10)
select @sex=sex
from dbo.student
if(@sex='f')
update dbo.student
set sex='m'
    else
    update dbo.student
set sex='f'
END
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Any error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Student
SET gender = CASE gender WHEN 'm' THEN 'f'
                         WHEN 'f' THEN 'm'
             END
```

Comment: @shubh, if this answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking on the checkbox icon in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

one way is  a CASE statement

```
UPDATE Student
set gender =case gender when'm' then 'f'
when 'f' then 'm' end
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter Version will be:

```
UPDATE Student
    SET gender = CASE gender WHEN 'm' THEN 'f' ELSE 'm' END
```